# Access self from decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, scope

In setUp() method of unittest I've setup some *self* variables, which are later referenced in actual tests. I've also created a decorator to do some logging. Is there a way in which I can access those *self* variables from decorator?

For the sake of simplicity, I'm posting this code:

```
def decorator(func):
    def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        # access a from TestSample
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _decorator

class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):    
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 10

    def tearDown(self):
        # tear down code

    @decorator
    def test_a(self):
        # testing code goes here
```

What would be the best way of accessing *a* (set in setUp()) from decorator?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Since you're decorating a method, and `self` is a method argument, your decorator has access to `self` at runtime.  Obviously not at parsetime, because there are no objects yet, just a class.

So you change your decorator to:

```
def decorator(func):
    def _decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # access a from TestSample
        print 'self is %s' % self
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return _decorator
```

Answer (score 2):

You could actually also use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to save the `help(obj.method)` information. In addition to that, if the decorator is only used in the class, it could be included to the class body:

```py
from functools import wraps


class MyClass:

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def _decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("In decorator. self: ", self)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return _decorator

    @decorator
    def somemethod(self, a: int, b: int = 5):
        """This is somemethod.

        Parameters
        ----------
        a:
            This is a.
        b:
            The b is optional argument. (Default: 5)
        """
        print("in somemethod")
```

Which works like this

```py
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj.somemethod()
In decorator. self:  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f0378df6920>
in somemethod
```

and will print the original docstring when calling help():

```
>>> help(obj.somemethod)

Help on method somemethod in module __main__:

somemethod(a: int, b: int = 5) method of __main__.MyClass instance
    This is somemethod.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    a:
        This is a.
    b:
        The b is optional argument. (Default: 5)
:
```

instead of this (when omitting `@wraps(func)`):

```
>>> help(obj.somemethod)

Help on method _decorator in module __main__:

_decorator(*args, **kwargs) method of __main__.MyClass instance
(END)
```

Comment: Your method works great, but when I call a function with the defined decorator, pycharms tells me, that the argument passed in my function should be self. This is incorrect, because it is a bound method and self will be passed in anyways. If you don't want this warning, you just have to decorate the decorator function with `@staticmethod`

Comment: @Hellow2 I came here exactly for your comment to see! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class based decorator implementation., here is an example.

```py
import functools
from typing import Any, Callable


class UpdateBackupStatus:

    def __call__(self, f: Callable) -> Any:
        @functools.wraps(wrapped=f)
        def wrapper(calling_instance, *args, **kwargs):
            batch_id = calling_instance.batch_id
            if batch_id is None:
                raise ValueError(
                    "batch_id is required"
                )
            # pre-logic goes here
            response = f(calling_instance, *args, **kwargs)
            # post-logic goes here
            return response
```

I personally don't like using `self` as the variable name in this context for referring the original caller. It might create readability issue. Instead call it with a different unique name ( in this example, I used - `calling_instance` )

Usage would be like :

```py
class SomeOtherClass:
    batch_id: str

    def __init__(
        self,
        batch_id: str,
    ):
        self.batch_id = batch_id

    @UpdateBackupStatus()
    def backup_table(self, table_name: str):
        # do something
        pass
```

The `batch_id` property of `SomeOtherClass` is now accessible from decorator.