# decorator to replace repetitive object orientated code?

Tags: python, decorator, pyside

I'm developing a GUI with Qt/PySide with lots of separate classes handling various widgets.  Each widget manages signals between buttons and other user inputs. I found myself having to reuse code to block widget signals at the start of method functions and then freeing up the signal at the end.  I decided to try and write a general decorator to do this for me.

I've searched through SO and tried to implement this the best I could with very little experience using decorators and so I'm not satisfied by my solution.

**My question is, what is the best way to write a general decorator that can access and run methods within that class which follow a clear format?  Is my method in anyway a good way?**

For clarity, here's what my code looks like with the repetitive code (I've removed some for brevity):

```
class WidgetController(...):

    def __init__(...):
       self.widget.myWidget.currentIndexChanged.connect(reactToChange)

    def reactToChange(...):
        self.widget.myWidget.blockSignals(True) # Repetetive line...
        ...
        self.widget.myWidget.blockSignals(False)

    def anotherFunction(...):
        self.widget.anotherWidget.blockSignals(True)
        ...
        self.widget.anotherWidget.blockSignals(False)
```

I would like something like the following:

```
class WidgetController(...):

   @blockSignals(myWidget)
   def reactToChange(...):
      ...

   @blockSignals(anotherWidget, alsoBlockThisWidget)
   def anotherFunction(...):
      ...
```

I have developed a decorator (with help from [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484872/in-python-why-doesnt-exec-work-in-a-function-with-a-subfunction) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590682/access-self-from-decorator)) but I hesitate to show it as it feels horribly clunky.   It uses `self` where I don't understand it as well as `exec` in nested functions and needs widget names to be passed as strings, but it does seem to work.  Here it is:

```
class BlockSignals(object):

    def __init__(self, *toBeBlocked):
        self.toBeBlocked = toBeBlocked

    def __call__(self, f):
        toBeBlocked = self.toBeBlocked
        def wrapped_f(self, *args):
            for b in toBeBlocked:
                exec 'self.widget.' + b + '.blockSignals(False)' in locals()
            f(self, *args)
            for b in toBeBlocked:
                exec 'self.widget.' + b + '.blockSignals(False)' in locals()
        return wrapped_f
```

Usage:

```
class WidgetController(...):

   @BlockSignals("myWidget")
   def reactToChange(...):
      ...

   @BlockSignals("anotherWidget", "alsoBlockThisWidget")
   def anotherFunction(...):
```

As you can see, it's not pretty.  I'd love to be able to get rid of the string parsing, get rid of the `exec`s, sort out the confusing `self`s and be able to implement it by passing it the actual widget object `@BlockSignals(self.widget.myWidget)`.  Unfortunately I've reached the limit of my ability, is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
import functools

def blockSignals(*widgetnames):
    def decorator(func):
        @functool.wraps(func)
        def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            widgets = [getattr(self.widget, name) for name in widgetnames]
            for widget in widgets:
                widget.blockSignals(True) 
            result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            for widget in widgets:
                widget.blockSignals(False)
            return result
        return method
    return decorator

class WidgetController(...):

    def __init__(...):
       self.widget.myWidget.currentIndexChanged.connect(reactToChange)

    @blockSignals('myWidget')
    def reactToChange(...):
        ...

    @blockSignals('anotherWidget', 'alsoBlockThisWidget')
    def anotherFunction(...):
        ...
```

You have to pass the *name* of the widget, not the widget itself, because the methods are defined at the time the *class* is defined, not when the *instance* is instantiated. The instance `self` and the actual widgets in `self.widget` do not exist at class-definition time.

The [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) decorator copies the name of the original function and its docstring to the decorated function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks great. Where is `func` passed to the decorator though?