# How to access class property in decorator in Python?

Tags: python, nose, nosetests, parameterized-unit-test, nose-parameterized

I am trying to use a `nose_parameterized` test and want to use it for a unittest method.

```
from nose.tools import assert_equal
from nose_parameterized import parameterized
import unittest

Class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
      def setUp(self):
           self.user1 = "Bar"
           self.user2 = "Foo"

      @parameterized.expand([
               ("testuser1",self.user1,"Bar"),
               ("testuser2",self.user2,"Foo")
                ]
      def test_param(self,name,input,expected):
          assert_equal(input,expected)
```

But `self` is not defined in the decorator function. Is there a workaround for this? I know that I can use global class variables but I need to use variables in `setUp`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590682/access-self-from-decorator and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-w-self-arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One workaround would be to use a string containing the attribute name in the decorator, and `getattr` in the test function:

```
@parameterized.expand([
           ("testuser1", "user1", "Bar"),
           ("testuser2", "user2", "Foo")
            ])
def test_param(self, name, input, expected):
    assert_equal(getattr(self, input), expected)
```

With this approach, `test_param` assumes that the value of its `input` argument is the attribute name whose value should be checked against `expected`.

Comment: To make this work, either the assignments to `self.user1` and `self.user2` in the OP's code should be modified to happen inside `__init__(self)`, or `user1` and `user2` should become class attributes. In the latter case your code would have to become `getattr(TestFoo, input)` but I assume the OP wants the former (otherwise why not just hard-code the `input` values "Foo" and "Bar" into the decorator).

Comment: @jez I believe this works as-is. `self.user1` and `self.user2` are assigned in the `setUp` method which is run before every test.

Comment: ah, I see, then it's just a case of the keyword `def` missing before `setUp` in the OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

The decorator is not run when you seem to assume it will be run.  In the following example:

```
class spam:
    @eggs
    def beans( self ):
        pass
```

remember that the use of the decorator is the same as saying:

```
beans = eggs( beans )
```

inside the `spam` scope, **immediately after the `def` statement itself is executed**.  When is a `def` statement executed? At the time the class and its methods are defined.  The decorator modifies the class-level definition of the method `spam.beans`, not the instance-level value of `self.beans`.  And of course, this occurs long before any *instances* of that class are ever created,  i.e. before a reference to any one particular instance, `self`, is ever meaningful.

If you want to attach a particular callable (e.g. a modified `test_param` callable that has certain arguments pre-baked into it using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)) to an instance `self`, you can of course do so *inside* one of the instance methods (e.g. `__init__` or `setUp`).

Some people will describe the class-definition code as happening at "parse time" and instance-level code as happening at "run time". You may or may not find that a helpful way of thinking about it, although really almost everything is "run-time" in Python.