# Decorator that gets self

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a decorator that can be added to instance methods and non-instance methods alike. I have reduced my code to a minimum example that demonstrates my point

```
def call(fn):
    def _impl(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    fn.call = _impl

    return fn

class Foo(object):
    @call
    def bar(self):
        pass

Foo().bar.call()
```

This gives the beautiful error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/511749370/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    Foo().bar.call()
  File "/tmp/511749370/main.py", line 3, in _impl
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Is it possible to do something like this without resorting to

```
Foo.bar.call(Foo())
```

Or is that my only option?

Comment: Look at the solution at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590682/access-self-from-decorator.
I know it is not the exact same problem but it might be helpful.

Comment: @IdanMeyer I tried adding `self` as a parameter to `_impl`, but that just shifted the error to `_impl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`, and I tried using `fn.__self__`, which raises an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement your decorator as a class and implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Basically, the descriptor `__get__` function is what's responsible for creating bound methods. By overriding this function, you get access to `self` and can create a bound copy of the `call` function.

The following implementation does exactly that. The `Foo` instance is saved in the `__self__` attribute. The decorator has a `__call__` method which calls the decorated function, and a `call` method which does the same thing.

```
import inspect
import functools
from copy import copy

class call:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.__self__ = None # "__self__" is also used by bound methods

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if bound to on object, pass it as the first argument
        if self.__self__ is not None:
            args = (self.__self__,) + args

        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            return self

        # create a bound copy of the decorator
        bound = copy(self)
        bound.__self__ = obj

        # update __doc__ and similar attributes
        functools.wraps(bound.func)(bound)
        bound.__signature__ = inspect.signature(bound.func)

        # add the bound instance to the object's dict so that
        # __get__ won't be called a 2nd time
        setattr(obj, self.func.__name__, bound)

        return bound
```

---

Test:

```
class Foo(object):
    @call
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

@call
def foo():
    print('foo')

Foo().bar.call() # output: bar
foo() # output: foo
```