# How to set self argument into decorator?

Tags: python, class, arguments, decorator

Can someone help me?
I have something like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    @test_dec('some param', self.arg2)
    def test_func():


        pass
```

But it doesn't work.
So, how can I put `self.arg2` to `test_dec`?

I want to do something like:

```
import socketio
sio = socketio.AsyncServer()

class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, options): 
        self.options = options 

    @sio.on('connect', namespace=self.options['namespace']) 
    def func(): pass
```

Comment: That makes no sense. There is no `self` in that context. What if I never create an instance of `MyClass`? What is `self` then? What is your decorator supposed to do, and why does it need access to the instance?

Comment: Related: [Access self from decorator](//stackoverflow.com/q/7590682)

Answer (score 0):

At first when there is nothing, there is no `self`. if you want to do it you should do something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    arg = 'something'       

    def __init__(self, *, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg = arg2

    @test_dec('some param', arg)
    def test_func():
        pass
```

But the value after initiating the class dosent effect the decorator. you should decorate you class with that `arg`.

or as Aran-Fey said check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590682/access-self-from-decorator) out, it will help you to decorate yourr class.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `arg2` in the decorator via the reference to `self`:

```
def test_dec(param):
  def outer(f):
    def wrapper(_self):
      _val = _self.arg2
      #do something
    return wrapper
  return outer

class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, *, arg1, arg2):
    self.arg1 = arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2
  @test_dec('some param')
  def test_func(self):
    pass
```

Comment: can you look at the my previous ask?