# Python decorate `class.method` that modify on `class.self`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-class

How to access `self` of the decorated method?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57807897/11671779), the self refer to the decorator:

```py
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.func.__name__)
        self.counter += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    @Decorator
    def method1(self):
        pass
```

Above example will cause:

```bash
      5 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
----> 6     self.counter += 1
      7     return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'Decorator' object has no attribute 'counter'
```

NOTE:

The `return self.func(*args, **kwargs)` is also causing error. I don't yet fully understand how to pass that to `A.method1`. The point is just that I want to update counter and printing `self.func.__name__`, that is all.

Comment: in `__call__(self, ...)`,`self` points to the instance to which the method is bound, hence a instance of `Decorator`, not of `A`

Comment: @cards Yeah, I know that. The problem is I don't know how to access the A instance.

Comment: does the decorator need to be a class-like?

Comment: @cards as long as it can update counter and access `method1.__name__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example with a function-like decorator, it can be generalized with no afford to other cases.

Hint: when using class decorators use another identifier for the self of the other class, `otherself`, ...

```
def dec(f):
    def __wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.counter += 1
        self.c.append(f.__name__)
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return __wrapper


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.c = []

    @dec
    def method1(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.method1()
a.method1()
print(a.counter, a.c)
2 ['method1', 'method1']
```